# JHipster Search entity by field of his entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I have Tournament entity. He have OneToOne relation with Prize entity. Prize entity have filed "amount". So if i want to do search Tournaments that have prize between some 2 values how can i do that using JHipster QueryService ?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the fact you are using QueryService, I'm assuming you enabled the [`Filtering` option](https://www.jhipster.tech/entities-filtering/) when generating your entities.  To query `Tournament` entities with a `Prize` amount between two values, a few things need to be added.

In `TournamentQueryService`, add the following to build a specification for the `prize.amount` field:

```
if (criteria.getPrizeAmount() != null) {
    specification = specification.and(buildReferringEntitySpecification(criteria.getPrizeAmount(), Tournament_.prize, Prize_.amount));
}
```

In `TournamentCriteria`, add a field for the `prizeAmount` filter: `private DoubleFilter prizeAmount;`.  Also add getters and setters.

Now you can test the request through Swagger (under menu Admin->API) and filter tournaments based on the prize amount field.

If you want to make this query in the client, you need to add two parameters to the HTTP request:

- `prizeAmount.greaterOrEqualThan`
- `prizeAmount.lessOrEqualThan`

You can add them in the `query` call like below, which will return Tournaments with prize amounts >= 1 and <= 5 (example is Angular):

```
loadAll() {
    this.tournamentService.query({
        'prizeAmount.greaterOrEqualThan': 1,
        'prizeAmount.lessOrEqualThan': 5
    }).subscribe(
        (res: HttpResponse<ITournament[]>) => {
            this.tournaments = res.body;
        },
        (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
    );
}
```

---

If you want the `TournamentDTO` to contain the prize amount as a field, the `prizeAmount` field needs to be added in the `TournamentDTO` (add field and getters/setters).  You also need to add `@Mapping(source = "prize.amount", target = "prizeAmount")` in `TournamentMapper` to map the prize data to that field in the `TournamentDTO`.

Comment: Now i have new issue. Tournament have @ManyToOne relation with Organizer so i would like to filter tournaments by organizer name. I would like to use CONTAINS but in query service in buildReferringEntitySpecification there is only equals. Can this be done ?

Comment: I have followed your instructions, it works for StringFilter (but it is not filtering the case of contains ).
For IntegerFilter it is giving error: ( java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default value must not be null at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor......).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to make that if we add another relation in Prize (Currency for example) and build specification ?

I didn't succeed because the definition is

`buildReferringEntitySpecification(Filter<X> filter,
        SingularAttribute<? super ENTITY, OTHER> reference,
        SingularAttribute<OTHER, X> valueField)`

So we have `buildReferringEntitySpecification(Filter<Long> filter,
        SingularAttribute<Tournament, Prize> reference,
        SingularAttribute<Prize, Currency *(instead of Long)*> valueField)`

Answer (score 0):

Please implement this method in your own class like below.

```
public static <ENTITY, ENTITY2> Specification<ENTITY> buildReferringEntitySpecification(
        Filter<Currency> filter,
        SingularAttribute<? super ENTITY, ENTITY2> reference,
        SingularAttribute<ENTITY2, Currency> valueField) {
        if (filter.getEquals() != null) {
            return buildEqualsJoin(filter.getEquals(), reference, valueField);
        } else if (filter.getIn() != null) {
            return buildInJoin(filter.getIn(), reference, valueField);
        } else if (filter.getSpecified() != null) {
            return buildByFieldSpecifiedJoin(filter.getSpecified(), reference, valueField);
        }
        return null;
    }
```