# JHipster criterias: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'io.github.jhipster.service.filter.BooleanFilter' for

Tags: java, jhipster

I have made the initial query with criteria like

```
this.trainingTeacherService
        .query({
          'training.game.id': '28',
          'teacher.user.login': this.currentAccount.login
        })
        .
```

at my frontend. And then I have added the new boolean parameter, existing at the model:

```
this.trainingTeacherService
        .query({
          'result': 'false',
          'training.game.id': '28',
          'teacher.user.login': this.currentAccount.login
        })
        .
```

and since that I'm getting the validation error message like this:

```
violations: [{field: "exported",…}]
0: {field: "exported",…}
field: "exported"
message: "Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'io.github.jhipster.service.filter.BooleanFilter' for property 'exported'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'io.github.jhipster.service.filter.BooleanFilter' for property
'exported': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"
```

So, why it was ok for the `String` fields to meet the criteria and not ok for the `Boolean`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have realized that for the Boolean field the criteria operation is always needed: so replacing the query to

```
this.trainingTeacherService
        .query({
          'result.equals': 'false',
          'trainingGameId.equals': '28',
          'teacherUserLogin.equals': this.currentAccount.login
        })
        .
```

made everything working, as the most prominent here is that `'result.equals': 'false'`, requires `equals` part, while the res ones are not, which, it fact, is a bit confusing. And also please note how the embedded objects should be explicitly added to the [service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51565096/jhipster-search-entity-by-field-of-his-entity)